# Show parent and it's children as a nav

Tags: structure, navigation, children

Newbie here with hopefully a simple question...

I have a structure as per the image below where I want to only show the parent item and it's children on their pages.

I want to exclude the other entries but they should show on their own pages.

[image: My structure]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access children through the entry's `descendants` property.

```
{# display event-information #}
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    {# display subsections #}
        <ul>
            {% for subsection in entry.descendants %}
                <li><a href="{{ subsection.url }}">{{ subsection.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can also use the `nav` tag, as described [in the documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/nav).

```
<ul id="nav">
    {% nav entry in entries %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

More generally speaking, you can use any of the following properties of the [EntryModel](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/EntryModel) to traverse the structure: `parent`, `children`, `descendants`, `ancestors`, `siblings`, `nextSibling`, `prevSibling`, and `level`.

Comment: Worth noting that the top example has a typo on line 7, the `<li>` element isn't closed, but rather a second `<li>`.

Comment: @ChristopherRobertKennedy Thanks! Fixed. Btw... feel free to edit when you find an obvious error like that, assuming you have permission.

Comment: For some reason, I was having problems accessing the edit feature in Chrome. Seems to work for me in Safari now, though. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Try using .level(1)

```
{% for eventsEntry in craft.entries.section('events').level(1) %}
    <div>
        {% set image = eventsEntry.pic.first() %}

        {% if image %}
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl('thumb') }}" alt="{{image.title}}"/>
        {% endif %}

        <h4 class="center">{{ eventsEntry.title }}</h4>

        {{ eventsEntry.shortDescription }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```